# Crear una página web con Html y Css

Tags: css, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Página de facilito</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='contenido'>
            <header>
                <hgroup>
                    <h1>codigofacilito.com</h1>
                </hgroup>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Inico</li>
                        <li><a href='Tutorial.html'>Tutoriales</a></li>
                        <li><a href='contacto.html'>Contacto</a></li>
                        <li>Media</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav> 

            </header>
            <section>
                <div id='textoPr'>
                    <article>
                        <hgroup>
                            <h1> Bienvenido a la pagina de codigo facilito </h1>
                        </hgroup>
                        <p>Estas por aprender a crear una página par aprender a hacer paginas </p>
                    </article>
                </div>              
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Me salen los siguientes errores:

> Warning: Consider using the `h1` element as a top-level heading
>   only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen
>   readers and other tools).
>
> From line 28, column 8; to line 28, column 11
>
> ```
> <h1> Bienv
> ```

> Warning: Section lacks heading. Consider using `h2`-`h6` elements to
>   add identifying headings to all sections.
>
> From line 24, column 8; to line 24, column 16
>
> ```
> ↩         <section>↩
> ```

Comment: Para tu primer warning puedes ver [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25996074/11685866) de SO en ingles. Para tu segundo warning esta [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24155024/11685866) igual de SO en ingles.

Comment: ¿Dónde te salen los warnings? Cuando ejecutas el código en Stack Snippet ¿se muestra coo esperas?

Comment: Es recomendable usar un único `h1` por página que sea el título principal de todo el contenido, por otra parte `hgroup` se eliminó de la especificación de HTML5 y no debería usarse

Answer (score 3):

dejó de utilizarse el html3, y segundo no deberías utilizar varios , trata de usar los otros títulos como lo son h2, h3... Esto permitiría poder jerarquizar los títulos.

Te dejo el código, espero te sirva.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Página de facilito</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='contenido'>
        <header>
                <h1>codigofacilito.com</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Inico</li>
                    <li><a href='Tutorial.html'>Tutoriales</a></li>
                    <li><a href='contacto.html'>Contacto</a></li>
                    <li>Media</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div id='textoPr'>
                <article>
                        <h2> Bienvenido a la pagina de codigo facilito </h2>
                    <p>Estas por aprender a crear una página par aprender a hacer paginas </p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

basicamente te esta problemas de SO, que te va ayudar con el pocicionamiento de tu sitio web, es decir estos errores no afectan la visualazacion de tu pagina pero si como el buscador de  google lo califica.

el SO dice que no debes repetir h1, por eso debes altenar segun un order jerargico los titulos de h1 hasta h2

los otros errores que te marcaba si no estoy mal usaste el w3 validation, y ese program te marcaba errores por que tenias contenedores innecesarios, tenias un div dentro de un section, me imagino que era para poner estilos, pero basta con ponerle el id al section

este codigo no te marcara mas problemas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Página de facilito</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='contenido'>
            <header>
                <hgroup>
                    <h1>codigofacilito.com</h1>
                </hgroup>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Inico</li>
                        <li><a href='Tutorial.html'>Tutoriales</a></li>
                        <li><a href='contacto.html'>Contacto</a></li>
                        <li>Media</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav> 

            </header>
            <section id='textoPr'>
                <hgroup>
                    <h2> Bienvenido a la pagina de codigo facilito </h2>
                </hgroup>
                <p>Estas por aprender a crear una página par aprender a hacer paginas </p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```